# How can I extract an HTML form value?

Tags: python, selenium

Hi I have the following in a page:

```
input id="cu_first_name" class="input_text" type="text" value="test_name" name="cu_name"
```

I am trying to extract the value and print it in python.
I use:

```
username = driver.find_element_by_id("cu_first_name")

print username.text
```

But this will not work since there is no actual text there, I need the "test_name" to be printed, pls help me!

Comment: It looks like you're using Selenium. Is that correct?

Comment: You are right I am, trying to automate some tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've gotten the element by id. From there, you need to get the element's attribute. Give the following a try:

```
username = driver.find_element_by_id("cu_first_name")
value = username.get_attribute('value')

print value
```